# If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable at $a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{|R(a,x)|}{|x-a|} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Where $R(a,x) = f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)$.  Via the "reverse" triangle inequality, wouldn't the limit be $\geq 0$?

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{|R(a,x)|}{|x-a|} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{|f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|} \geq \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{|f(x)-f(a)|}{|x-a|} - |f'(a)| =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by your argument we get $\geq 0$.  But we can also write 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{|R(a,x)|}{|x-a|}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \left| \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)\right|=0. $$